# is oracle database architecture single tier, two tier or multi tier?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm currently learning oracle database administration 10g. I was wondering to which tier oracle architecture belongs?

Comment: "oracle" is many things. which architecture?

Comment: Why are you learning 10g adminstration when that version is reaching the end of its extended support period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional three tier model is

```
client -> application server -> data storage
```

The data storage is usually a database, so this tier is nomrally referred to as the database tier.

So that's where the Oracle database sits.  Other parts of the Oracle architecture will sit in other places.  For instance SQL Plus is a client and sits in the client layer with direct access to the database (two-tier), where as OEM these days is a browser based client with an app server layer (three-tier).

Of course, modern enterprises often have more complicated arcitecturs with many tiers (in-memory databases/caches, SANs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database has a client server architecture.

From the documentation:

> In the Oracle client/server architecture, the database application and
>   the database are separated into two parts: a front-end or client
>   portion, and a back-end or server portion. The client executes the
>   database application that accesses database information and interacts
>   with a user through the keyboard, screen, and pointing device such as
>   a mouse. The server executes the Oracle software and handles the
>   functions required for concurrent, shared data access to an Oracle
>   database.

The Client in this case could be a number of things including sqlplus, Toad (or any other IDE), Java, .net among others.